# Convert Strings to Type Instances

Tags: c#, type-conversion

have you any alternative to these code, i want a more generic code 
I tried Convert class but with no success

```
        public object convert(Type type, string value)
        {
            object r = null;
            if (type == typeof(bool))
            {
                r = bool.Parse(value);
            }            
            else if (type == typeof(int))
            {
                r = int.Parse(value);
            }
            else if (type == typeof(string))
            {
                r = value;
            }

            return r; 
        }
```

Comment: Might be a big change, but you could (while raising other issues) get rid of the entire problem by using dynamic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
return conv.ConvertFromInvariantString(value);
```

Other conversion operations exist if you don't want "invariant". It depends on your needs. See also `ConvertFromString` if you want locale settins to apply, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You mention you have tried the `Convert` class, but have you also tried `Convert.ChangeType(value, type)`? What where the problems you ran in to?

Comment: Yes I'v tried these but the problem that I cant cast the result

Comment: The result of that method is returned as `object`, just like your method does. At some point you will have to go through either a bunch of `if`s like in your example. Unfortunately you can't `switch` on a type.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a dictionary `Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>`?

Maybe something like this:

```
public static class MyConverter
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> _Converters;

    static MyConverter()
    {
        _Converters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>();

        // Add converter from available method
        _Converters.Add(typeof(double), MySpecialConverter);
        // Add converter as lambda
        _Converters.Add(typeof(bool), (text) => bool.Parse(text));
        // Add converter from complex lambda
        _Converters.Add(typeof(int), (text) =>
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
            }

            return int.Parse(text);
        });
    }

    private static object MySpecialConverter(string text)
    {
        return double.Parse(text);
    }

    public static object Convert(Type type, string value)
    {
        Func<string, object> converter;

        if (!_Converters.TryGetValue(type, out converter))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No converter for type " + type.Name + " available.");
        }

        return converter(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ChangeType()` method doesn't convert to null-able types, `Guid`, `Enums` etc. This [implementation of ChangeType](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2012/03/06/Convert-to-unknown-generic-type-ChangeType-T.aspx) will convert it all.